# Question not appearing in user's profile

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, revisions-list, question-lists

In the [revision history of question 1332120](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1332120/revisions), it says that the question was asked by **Jeff Atwood♦**. However, the question

- does not appear in [the question list in his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=questions)
- does not appear in [search
  (keywords: `is:question user:1`)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+user%3A1)
- does not appear in [the Data Explorer
  (query: `SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Posts.OwnerUserId=1 AND Posts.PostTypeId=1`)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148515)

Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332120/whats-your-favourite-jquery-plugin It says that omg wrote the question... http://stackoverflow.com/users/104015/omg?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=2

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy OK now I'm confused.

Comment: @Qantas It says that omg has 100% of the content; [Jeff Atwood wrote the question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1332120/1)

Comment: I bet it's to do with community wiki.

Comment: Close-voters: While he did reference a question that'snow deleted, this isn't really "localized" in that sense. This does happen elsewhere on more than just *that* question. For example, I'm now the [proud owner of a question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18651446/revisions) I didn't write.

Comment: @animuson not owner, just the author of the first undeleted revision. :) Seriously now, I believe deleted revision should still be there (i.e. number and author) and just say "deleted" in its content somehow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know what exactly was in that question, but this happens when a moderator edits something out of the post and the previous revision gets burned (usually when it contains personal information). According to the timeline, the post was created by omg. Jeff must have removed and burned something from the question. I don't really care to investigate it any further because that's a total crap question which will be deleted *very shortly*.

Comment: Aaand it's gone.

Comment: I'm so glad to see a response from someone I voted for in the last moderator election.

Answer (score 4):

That question might even be before we had mod powers to burn a specific revision (i.e. it might have been ad hoc altered via sql).

Regardless, the current feature that allows a mod to destroy a revision will ensure the original post owner retains the initial revision, so this won't happen any more.

Comment: Is that a recent change to the feature? Because [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18651446/revisions) is pretty recent...

Comment: Hmm, I tested it on dev before commenting about ownership retention and there were no issues... GREAT, ANOTHER BUG!